# MVC GetAsync not working and doesn't throw any exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I have code like this:

```
public async Task<string> getToken()
        {
            string uri = "http://localhost/api/getToken";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

            string token = "asfd";
            string baseId = "asfasdf";
            string appVersion = "afsadf";

            string content = "";

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                string url = string.Format("{0}?token='{1}'&baseId='{2}'&appVersion='{3}'", uri, token, baseId, appVersion);
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


            return content;
        }
```

And when I get to the line when is GetAsync called VS turn off debug mode and does not throw any exception.
On the server I have breakpoint in the action in controller (mvc web api) and it is not reached.
But when I copy url and past it to the browser action in controller is invoked.
And when I change my url for some other incorrect url, GetAsync throw exception which is captured in catch.
My application is in .net framework 4.5, console application.
Maybe I must add any dll ?

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint in the catch and on the statement after the call to GetAsync? Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Where are you making this call from? A console application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete. That's why it gets to that `aysnc` call, the method returns the task that represents the operation and then the application ends.

You need to `await` the task `getToken` returns by using `await getToken()`. If you call `getToken` from the `main` method, which can't be `async` you need to use `Task.Wait` to wait synchronously:

```
static void Main()
{
    getToken().Wait();
}
```